# Django Model's Value Error while inserting data into model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to insert *form-data* into models `User` and `UserGroup` using `APIView`.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures/', max_length=None, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'


class UserGroup(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, related_name='role_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank= False)
```

I am able to insert data into model `User` but when I try to do the same with the model `UserGroup` it returns an error.

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "17": "UserGroup.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

I want this API to create a user and assign a role immediately to the newly created user by inserting `role_id` and `user_id` in model `UserGroup`.

I have created two different serializer `UserSerializer` and `UserGroup` serializer and both has its own create method to push an instance into model. Also, in post request payload I am accepting all the fields of `User` model but for `UserGroup` model I am just accepting `role` field and not the `user` field as its value needs to be generated once the user is created.

I will have to use transaction as well to roll back if in case a user is created but the API has failed to assign the role to that user. So, I want to know is this an appropriate way to accomplish this task. 
class UserAPIViews(APIView):

```
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

def post(self, request, format=None):

    user_group={} #dictionary for UserGroupSerializer

    user_group['role'] = request.data['user_group'] # adding Role object to UserGroup dictionary from request payload.

    del request.data['user_group'] # removing user_group (key,value) from the payload so that dictionary could used for UserSerializer

    user_serialized_data = serializers.UserSerializer(data=request.data) # Serializing request payload dictionary with the UserSerializer

    if user_serialized_data.is_valid(): # check the dictionary is validated or invalidated by the UserSerializer

        try:

            user_created_with_id = user_serialized_data.save() # if the dictionary is validated save the UserSerilaized instance to the User model.
            # if the reqest payload dictionary is saved successfully then the save() will return the id of newly created object.
        except IntegrityError as error:

            message = f'Email already exist.'

            return Response ({
                'error_message' : message,
                'status' : status.HTTP_226_IM_USED
            })

    else:
        return Response ({'user_serilization_error':user_serialized_data.error_messages}) # return Payload dictionary has been invalidated by the UserSerilaizer.
    # add the user parameter to the user_group dictionary. The value of key user should be the object id of newly created user.
    user_group['user'] = user_created_with_id
    # now the UserGroupSerilaizer dictionary is ready.
    # user_group ={"user":user_created_with_id, "role":<Role: Role object (2)>} 
    # serilaize the user_group dictionary with the UserGroupSerilaizer.
    # this is where it generates a ValueError stating that UserGroup.user must be a User instance.
    user_group_serialized_data = serializers.UserGroupSerializer(data=user_group)

    if user_group_serialized_data.is_valid():

        user_group_id = user_group_serialized_data.save()

        success_message = 'User has been created.'

        return Response({
            'success_message' : success_message,
            'status' : status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        })
    else:
        return Response ({'user_group_serilization_error':user_serialized_data.error_messages})
```

**UserGroupSerializer**

```
class UserGroupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserGroup

    user = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    role = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_role_relation_id = UserGroup.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return user_role_relation_id
```

**UserSerializer**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    profile_picture = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=True, use_url= False, required=False)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length = 255, write_only=True, required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        user_id = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

        return user_id
```

API request has the payload as stated below -

```
{
"first_name":"", # Serialized by UserSerializer
"last_name":"", # Serialized by UserSerializer
"email":"", # Serialized by UserSerializer
"password":"", # Serialized by UserSerializer
"profile_picture":"", # Serialized by UserSerializer
"user_role:":"" # Serialized by UserGroupSerializer
}
```

I had to split this payload into two different dictionaries, one to be serialized by `UserSerializer` and another to be serialized by `UserGroupSerializer`.

Please read the comments of APIView class to understand the flow.

Comment: on which line does it throw the error?

it looks like you are passing the ID of the user (17) instead of resolving the Id to the user object`

Comment: @bb4L it throws an error in this line - `user_group_id = user_group_serialized_data.save() `

Comment: can you check what's in the data you pass to the serializer and also how the `user_group_serialized_data` looks like? i think in there somewhere is the "17" where it should have a user object, so i think you have to modify this data before passing in the serializer, modifying in the sense of resolving the id to the **User object**

Comment: @bb4L the `user_group_serialized_data` looks like this `{'role': <Role: Role object (2)>, 'user': 17}`. Also, both the fields of `UserGroupSerializer` are `IntegerFields`. I understand that just like `role's` **value** the `user's` **value** should be resolved to **User object**. So I have also tried it by doing this - `user_group['user'] = User.objects.get(pk=user_created_with_id)`  but unlike `Role.objects.get(pk=some_value)`, it returns an **email** as a **User object** and what I need is an **id** as a **User object**. Could you please help me by posting an answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

ValueError: Cannot assign "17": "UserGroup.user" must be a "User" instance.
 this error says that have to give a user instanceas input 
  UserGroup.user  = user_object

you can do that by :

```
current_user = User.objects.get(id = 17)
UserGroup.user = current_user
```

or

```
UserGroup.user = request.user
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in the UserGroupSerializer

have you looked at this: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects

(you shouldn't have to adjust the

```
   user_group['user']
```

sorry for the confusion in the comment)

Comment: Yes I have been through the documentation of **dealing with the nested objects** but it won't really help to solve this problem as I don't have any nested objects in payload. I have updated my question to explain briefly about this.

Comment: Can you try with nested objects because the reason why they are nested in the example is that they are related and so are your models

otherwise you have to override the save method of the `usergroupserializer` and resolve the integer to a user object